# How can I tell if I'm using Proguard to obfuscate my code?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I have an app that I migrated from Eclipse to Android-Studio. I want to make sure I'm using Proguard for my release version. I see in my build.gradle file this:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```

However, I don't have a proguard-android.txt or proguard-rules.txt in my project's folder. Is my code being obfuscated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your code is not being obfuscated. You are not running proguard.  `minifyEnabled` controls whether to run proguard, and you have it set to `false`, need to change that to `true` to turn on proguard.  `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')` gets the default proguard rules from the SDK.  See [`proguardFiles` docs](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:proguardFiles).

To check that your code is being obfuscated, you can look in your `build/outputs/mapping/release` directory.  Those files should have modification times from during your build.  Looking at the `mapping.txt` will give the obfuscation details (which names were mapped to what).

Answer (score 1):

proguard-android.txt is system file .u need not to care.[image]

'proguard-rules.txt is here . if u havent ,u can add a empty file. u can use ur custom name . But when minifyEnabled is true ,u need to add some line in it.